# Error in build procces in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, amber-framework

Well I'm using amberframework and it have built-in webpack building the issue is that when I'm trying to import an image via scss it can't handle the image file and can't find as I understand it.

The thing is most of the source cod located in folder called src and so are the assets. During build step it should transfer the files to the public folder but it doesn't and instead output this weird error.

The error:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/stylesheets/main.scss
    Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/transparent.jpg' in '/Users/niko/code/blog/src/assets/stylesheets'
        at factoryCallback (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:282:40)
        at factory (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:237:20)
        at resolver (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20)
        at asyncLib.parallel (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20)
        at /Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3888:9
        at /Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
        at iteratorCallback (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1062:13)
        at /Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
        at /Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3885:13
        at resolvers.normal.resolve (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:119:22)
        at onError (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:65:10)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at runAfter (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
        at innerCallback (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
        at /Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at runAfter (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
        at innerCallback (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
        at innerCallback (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
        at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at afterInnerCallback (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:168:10)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/Users/niko/code/blog/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
     @ ./src/assets/stylesheets/main.scss

    ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/assets/stylesheets/main.scss
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/transparent.jpg' in '/Users/niko/code/blog/src/assets/stylesheets'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/assets/stylesheets/main.scss 7:83-118
     @ ./src/assets/stylesheets/main.scss
```

The code webpack file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

let config = {
  entry: {
    'main.bundle.js': './src/assets/javascripts/main.js',
    'main.bundle.css': './src/assets/stylesheets/main.scss'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      amber: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../lib/amber/assets/js/amber.js')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'file-loader?name=/[name].[ext]'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('main.bundle.css'),
  ],
  // For more info about webpack logs see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/
  stats: 'errors-only'
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the .jpg file inside '/Users/niko/code/blog/src/assets/stylesheets' path?

Comment: That's the issue, the sass file is inside `/Users/niko/code/blog/src/assets/stylesheets` 

But the images are in `/Users/niko/code/blog/src/assets/images`


In the end the images should be iniside `/Users/niko/code/blog/public/assets/images`

Answer (score 0):

This part of the error code tells us what's wrong. The relative path is incorrect.
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/transparent.jpg' in '/Users/niko/code/blog/src/assets/stylesheets'`

It's looking for `/Users/niko/code/blog/src/assets/stylesheets/images/transparent.jpg`

When you reference the jpg from the sass file, it should be one more folder back with a dot dot slash. `../images/transparent.jpg`. Instead of starting to look in stylesheets, it will look from assets.